# Nested enum in Python

Tags: python

I'm working with regex patterns for several categories and want to encapsulate them in a nested enum. What I liked of mixing in a `str` type is that the value is immediately available, without `.value`, such as:

```
class Colours(str, Enum):
    RED = 'red'

Colours.RED == 'red'
>>> True
```

I want have this feature in a nested enum but I'm not sure if this is possible.

```
class Blues(str, Enum):
    DARKBLUE = 'darkblue'
    LIGHTBLUE = 'lightblue'

class Colours(Enum):
    RED = 'red'
    BLUE = Blues

Colours.RED == 'red'
>>> False
Colours.BLUE.DARKBLUE == 'darkblue'  # I would like this is be True
>>> AttributeError: 'Colours' object has no attribute 'DARKBLUE'
Colours.BLUE.value.DARKBLUE.value == 'darkblue'
>>> True
```

Comment: Why does your Enum inherit from `str`?

Comment: Enums aren't "really" classes in the way you typically think bout classes. They just use the `class` statement machinery to implement a syntax that doesn't actually do what it looks like it is doing. For example, the assignment `RED = 'red'` in this case is more like shorthand for something like `Colors.RED = Colours.__new__(Colours, 'red')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option to remove the `Enum` entirely:

```py
class Blues:
    DARKBLUE = 'darkblue'
    LIGHTBLUE = 'lightblue'


class Colours:
    RED = 'red'
    BLUE = Blues


print(Blues.DARKBLUE)  # Blues.DARKBLUE
print(Colours.BLUE.DARKBLUE)  # Blues.DARKBLUE
```

Comment: To be honest, this makes more sense. I was a bit stuck in using enums.

Answer (score 0):

Getting rid of the inheritances seems to work (using python v3.10)

```
class Blues:
    DARKBLUE = "darkblue"
    LIGHTBLUE = "lightblue"


class Colours:
    RED = "red"
    BLUE = Blues


print(Colours.BLUE.DARKBLUE == "darkblue")
>>> True
```

The same should also work if you use dataclasses.